# Selecting multiline-text on focus using jQuery

Tags: jquery

This istructions does not work with multiline text-box:

```
$("input:text").mouseup(function () { $(this).select(); });
```

I have to simlpy select all text inside texbox on my page.

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Do you want all the text to be selected on blur, click, hover off, what event?

Comment: I want to select text onMouseUp: when a user leave the click on the input:text